# Strange margins with Google Chrome (HTML)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm making a site (HTML, CSS, PHP) and I'm having a problem with a strange margin appearing only with Google Chrome, it works fine with Firefox or IE. Even if I remove my Stylesheet, there still is this strange margin.
How to remove it ?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" /> -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fresca|Dosis:200,300,400,500,600,700,800|Cabin+Condensed:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title>My Site</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include("./php/header.php"); ?>
        <?php include("./php/profile.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is what Google Chrome shows me when I inspect the element:

Have a look at this pic
[image]

Blank lines are causing those margins but I don't know what they do here.

Comment: remove all the witespace so all your code is written in one line, save and refresh. after you can again make it look nice and clean with new lines and whitespaces. sometimes this can happen cause of copy pasting and there are invisible signs in your markup causing the issue

Comment: What's in your `./php/header.php`? :)

Comment: Only this: http://pastebin.com/UQmhvQxP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really weird... Maybe it's an encoding problem. Please open your php file with notepad++ and in Format menu choose encode in **utf-8 without BOM**.

Comment: You were right ! :) I was encoding the file in UTF-8, but I still don't know why it happened because I always encode files in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body><?php
   include("./php/header.php");
   include("./php/profile.php"); ?></body>
```

The white spaces between `<?php` tag and `<body>` tag are visible and can add additional margin.

Comment: It didn't work but Chrome is now showing just "" instead of those "     "

Comment: @Claymeuns It's also a good practice to add a `reset.css` to your page. It removes every browser-specific styling and unifies them. The most popular I think is the Eric Mayer's one:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: This is very strange, even if I replace my CSS by this reset.css, there still is those margins.